# PowerShell script - Converting PDFs to TIFs using Ghostscript

Tags: powershell, ghostscript

What am I missing here?

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR converting File
E:\DocuTA\TIFs\06fef98e-e1c5-405e-93ea-c684ee7a856d.tif 
nvoke-Expression : You must provide a value expression on the
right-hand side of the '-' operator.  At E:\DocuTA\ConvPDFtoTIF.ps1:31
char:26 + $ret = invoke-expression <<<< -command $cmdline +
CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException +
FullyQualifiedErrorId :
ExpectedValueExpression,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

when running this script:

```
#recursively crawls the directory tree and converts pdf files to tif files
#compresses the images to a smaller file size.

$Now = get-date
$Days = "14"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$srcfolder = "E:\DocuTA\PDFs\"
$destfolder = "E:\DocuTA\TIFs\"
$convert = "& C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin32c.exe"
$filter = "*.pdf"
$dest_ext = "tif"
$arg1 = @(" -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -r300x300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH ")
$lfpath = "E:\DocuTA\Logs\"
$logfile = new-item -type file -name "PDF2TIFLog$(get-date -uformat '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').log" -path "$lfpath"
$elogfile = "E:\DocuTA\Logs\PDF2TIFErrorLog.log"
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
$count = 0
Write-Output "`nStarting ... ($Now)" | Out-File -Append $logfile
Try
{
foreach ($srcitem in $(Get-ChildItem $srcfolder -Include $filter -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt "$LastWrite"}))
{
$count++
$srcname = $srcitem.FullName
$partial = $srcitem.FullName.Substring($srcfolder.Length)
$destname = $destfolder+$partial
$destname = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($destname,$dest_ext)
$destpath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($destname)
$cmdline = "'"+$convert+"'"+"'"+$srcname+"'"+$arg1+ "'"+$destname+"'"
Write-Output "[$count] $cmdline" | Out-File -Append $logfile
$ret = invoke-expression -command $cmdline
Write-Output "[$count] OUTPUT: $ret" | Out-File -Append $logfile
Write-Output "[$count] processed file." | Out-File -Append $logfile
}
}
Catch
{
$Now | out-file -Append $elogfile
write-output "ERROR converting File $destname" | out-file -Append $elogfile
Write-Output $Error[0] | out-file -Append $elogfile
}
Finally 
{
Write-Output "Finished processing files. Total: $count`n" | Out-File -Append $logfile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PowerShell doesn't like using - for switches, try using # instead

Comment: If I run from the Windows command prompt I get prompted for each page.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.16\bin\gswin32c.exe" "E:\DocuTA\PDFs\06fef98e-e1c5-405e-93ea-c684ee7a856d.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -r300x300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 –dNOPROMPT  -dBATCH "E:\DocuTA\TIFs\06fef98e-e1c5-405e-93ea-c684ee7a856d.tif"

Processing pages 1 through 99. Page 1

Loading NimbusSan-Bol font from

%rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSan-Bol... 3866684 2360

085 8995292 7655146 3 done.

Loading NimbusSan-Reg font from

%rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSan-Reg... 3899796 2450

968 9035492 7692024 3 done.

>>showpage, press to continue<<

Comment: You've put the input file before the switches, so it will process that before reading the remainder of the command line. Put the input file last.

Comment: I updated the following below and it's now working.                          $cmdline = """$convert""" +$arg1 +"""$destname"""+" "+"""$srcname"""                               $ret = invoke-expression -command "& $cmdline"